# How to rearrange two factor data in R to run two way ANOVA?

Tags: r, dataframe, anova

I need to run two way ANOVA and post-hoc test in R.
And I have a CSV file like this:

```
BLOCK,AdvTraining,Destillation,Squeezing
Clean,4,3,10
Clean,10,3,13
Clean,4,1,8
FGSM,402,237,521
FGSM,290,129,483
FGSM,407,262,568
BIM,998,14,285
BIM,972,9,321
BIM,994,12,451
DeepFool,421,419,661
DeepFool,410,425,663
DeepFool,378,386,585
```

There are 4 blocks (Clean, FGSM, BIM, DeepFool) and 3 treatments (AdvTraining, Destillation, Squeezing).

All blocks have same number of samples, without missing value.

This file is intended to run two way ANOVA from excel.

I notice R require a single column structure, something like this:

```
Clean,AdvTraining,4
Clean,Destillation,3
Clean,Squeezing,10
...
DeepFool,AdvTraining,378
DeepFool,Destillation,386
DeepFool,Squeezing,585
```

How can I do this?

Notice that the actual file is much larger.
It has more blocks and more than 500 rows.
So changing it manually isn't an option.

Comment: `tidyr::pivot_longer(df, cols = -BLOCK)`

Comment: @RonakShah Thanks. This package works. The `reshape` and `melt` methods are too convoluted.